# boost function with optional parameters

Tags: c++, function, boost, optional-parameters

I have a map containing `boost::function` values, as defined below:

```
std::map <std::string, boost::function<std::string (std::string, int)> > handlers;
```

Let us say I define the following function:

```
using namespace std;
string substring (string input, int index = 0){
    if (index <= 0){
        return input;
    }
    stringstream ss;
    for (int j = index; j<input.length(); j++){
        ss << input[j];
    }

    return ss.str();
}
```

I would like to be able to store this in the handlers map, but WITH it's optional parameter.  Does boost have a way to perform this?  I have looked at `boost::optional`, but that doesn't seem to do what I want.

**EDIT**

To give a little more background, there are a few handlers that require extra arguments, such as a pointer to a dictionary (`typedef std::map < std::string, std::string > dictionary`) or something, because they make changes to that dictionary.  However, the majority of the handlers do not touch the dictionary in question, but, in order to store them all in the same map, they all must take the same arguments (have the same template for `boost::function`).  The goal is to make the functions that don't deal with the dictionary at all usable without having to either A) create a dictionary for the sole purpose of passing it and not using it or B) copy the code verbatim into another function that doesn't require that argument.

The code above is a simplified example of what I am doing.

Comment: I couldn't find any way to do this (which doesn't mean it's impossible), but I can imagine why they wouldn't want this functionality: How would you be able to call that function with it's optional parameter once you have it? Say you're going through your map calling functions, you need to provide two parameters to each function, unless it has optional parameters?

Comment: The purpose is to have this function available externally, in addition to being in the handlers map.  This way I could either call `handlers[key]("hello", 2);` or call `substring("hello");`.  I will also add some information to the question to give you some background as to why this is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: This is not possible in C++ without a lot of additional code.

The long answer:
Default values for function arguments in C++ are only used when they are needed in a context where the function's **name** appears. If you call a function through other means (like a function pointer, or `boost::function/std::function`, the information about there possibly being default arguments is not available to the compiler, so it can't fill them in for you.

As a background, this is how default arguments work in C++:
When you have the expression `substring(MyString)` (with `std::string MyString = "something"`), then the compiler looks for all functions called `substring` and finds `string substring(string, int=0)`. This function takes two parameters, one of which can have a default value, which makes the function viable. To actually call the function, the compiler changes the source code so that it reads `substring(MyString, 0)` and proceeds to generate code based on that adaptation.

To be able to use default values with an indirect call, like through `boost::function`, you effectively have to emulate the default argument mechanism of the compiler.